# I want to show my images in fancybox but my fancybox is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, fancybox

I have fancybox for the image gallery and in this, I add `data-fancybox="gallery"` but it not working properly

My code:

```
 <section id="gallery" class="bg-lighter">
      <div class="container-fluid pt-70 pb-0">
         <div class="section-title text-center">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                  <h2 class="text-uppercase title" >Our <span class="text-white font-weight-300">Gallery</span></h2>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="section-content">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                 <div class="gallery-lsit">
              <?php foreach ($gallery_imgs as $img):?> 
                  <figure class="col-md-3">
                      <a class="img-popup pan" data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?php echo base_url();?><?php echo $img['image_url']; ?>">
                          <img alt="picture" src="<?php echo base_url(); echo $img['thumbnail_url']; ?>" class="img-fluid">
                      </a>
                      <h3 class="text-center my-3"><?php echo $img['title']?></h3>
                  </figure>
              <?php endforeach;?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

In this above code it just open image but in this there is no `cancel` button and `next` or `previous` buttons are missing.

Comment: @kerbholz I remove that code

Comment: Your title says you're using lightbox, but `data-fancybox` suggests you're using fancybox, which is it?

Comment: @kerbholz but `fancybox` is also not working

Comment: Which one are you using? Have you included/loaded the appropriate scripts/styles in your html? Do you get errors in your browser console?

Comment: @kerbholz I uploaded `<script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js">` `</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css">`  these files.

Comment: You also need to load `jquery` first. I changed "lightbox" in your question to "fancybox" since that's what you're using. Make sure your scripts all load and you don't get any errors in your javascript console.

Comment: Hit F12 in your browser and check console tab for any message. I am sure there will be a clue.

Comment: Also, you are using relative paths - `src="fancybox/..`, are you sure you do not need to have smth like `src="/fancybox/..`? Anyway, it just should work if you have included all files correctly.